# Indentation after entering subsection (overleaf)

Tags: latex, indentation

I am having an issue where the indentation is not working when I enter a special section environment. In the preamble I have \setlength\parindent{24pt}. However as soon as I enter a new section environment I have created, the indentation no longer works. Any ideas on how to fix this bug?

Comment: Adding some more lines of your latex code in a code block, and providing a annotated screenshot of the output will help attracting people that can answer your question. (Unfirtunately I am just reviewing your post, and -excapt for home decorating- have no latex experience)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `indentfirst` package to also indent the first line of a section:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{indentfirst}

\setlength\parindent{24pt}

\begin{document}

\section{title}

\lipsum



\end{document}
```